# Can't seem to receive events from client in socketio in namespaces outside of "connection"

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am currently trying to emit an event across namespaces, yet I can't seem to do that. If I set up a listener outside on `io.on('connection', async function (socket) {}`, it does not work. Here is my code:

**[Server]**

```
const io = socket(server); // binds http server

// accounts route to handle CRUD operations for accounts
const accountsHandler = io
  .of('/api/accounts')
  .on('connection', async function (socket) {
    socket.emit('received accounts', { accounts: await accountsAPI.getAccounts() });

    socket.on('add account', async function({ username, password }) {
      let accounts = await accountsAPI.addAccount({ username, password });
      console.log("Adding account...");
      console.log("Username: " + username);

      gramHandler.emit('new account', accounts[accounts.length-1]);

      socket.emit('received accounts', { accounts });
    });

    socket.on('remove account', async function({ key }) {
      let accounts = await accountsAPI.removeAccount(key);
      socket.emit('received accounts', { accounts });
    });
  });
```

If imove the event `add account` outside to

```
accountsHandler.on('add account', async function({ username, password }) {
  let accounts = await accountsAPI.addAccount({ username, password });
  console.log("Adding account...");
  console.log("Username: " + username);

  gramHandler.emit('new account', accounts[accounts.length-1]);

  socket.emit('received accounts', { accounts });
});
```

It doesn't work. I do not think I have to do it this way. The current goal is to emit an even in `gramHandler` when `accountHandler` receives the `add account` event.

```
const gramHandler = io
  .of('/api/gram')
  .on('connection', async function (socket) {
    socket.on('new account', async function({ username, password, key }) {
      console.log("Adding new account " + username);

      let proxy = await get_proxy(proxies);
      let instance = new api(username, password, proxy['http']);
      instance.login();
      instances[key] = instance;
    });
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way, whenever there is a new connection, socketio creates a socket object for that connection, and it's provided in a callback hence

```
io.on('connection', async functoin(socket) {

})
```

AND IT IS VERY IMPORTANT TO PAY ATTENTION THAT HERE WE ARE USING THE OBJECt `io` AND NOT SOCKET

However, whenever you want to capture an even that's coming from a socket then you do `socket.on()` and `socket` only exists in the scope under `io.on` hence extracting the function wont work.

Moreover, in your `add account` function you are using `socket.emit` to respond, but socket doesn't even exist. If you want to modularize, you can use something like redis and cache all connected sockets and then you loop through them and use `each socket.on`, but I don't recommend this method because it can be very resources intensive.

Your next bet is to separate the add account function and whenever a socket has an event just call the function and pass the socket as a parameter

For example:

```
io.on('connection', async function(socket) {
    socket.on('add account', async function({ username, password }) {
          addAccount(username, password, socket)
    })

})


function addAccount(username, password, socket) {
// Your addAccount logic goes here
}
```

You can modularize this as you wish and separate functions into different files.

Goodluck

Comment: I think there is a problem with this. In my code, I want an event to happen in the `gramHandler` socket when 'add account' is received in the `accountHandler` socket`

Comment: I have tried using `gramHandler.emit('new account', accounts[accounts.length-1])` in the `accountsHandler` namespace to emit an event to `gramHandler`, and `gramHandler.on('new account', async function({ username, password, key })` in the `gramHandler` namespace, but it doesn't seem to work, because either `gramhandler` never got the `event` or `accoutnshandler` never emitted it

Comment: so let me understand this, you have 2 socket nodes running on the same machine? and you want one to emit to the other?

Comment: I believe so? I have 2 namespaces running on the same script